# Pinging (ICMP) Docker container on AWS ECS

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, docker, icmp, amazon-ecs

I've got a script running in a Docker container that listens for ICMP packets. If you ping the container IP address, it picks them up and sends an email.

However I'm having a bit of difficulty pinging this container from the **outside**.

The server IP is 53.*.*.* and the container IP is 172.*.*.*.

How do I ping (ICMP) the container externally? Pinging the 53.*.*.* address doesn't reach the container as the instance itself resonds to pings. I've let this container run over the weekend and some external pings seem to have rached the container externally, but not sure how!

Comment: *"some external pings seem to have rached the container externally, but not sure how!"* You should probably look into that, because it should not be possible to access an RFC-1918 address (172.16.0.0 ... 172.31.255.255 is among the blocks included here) from the internet, without some kind of network address translation.